# Import 3rd Party JS file into Angular component

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, angular5

I'm trying to import this DataTable Jquery plugin in Angular 5 (I include both scripts after JQuery and Bootstrap have been loaded)

"https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"
"https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"

But I keep getting this error:

> ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_jquery_dist_jquery___default(...)(...).DataTable is not a function

I've added the dependencies to the `angular-cli.json`:

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        "../3rdParty/data-tables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
        "../3rdParty/data-tables/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"
      ],
```

and in my `component.ts` file I import jquery and the plugin

```
import $ from 'jquery/dist/jquery';
import * as dt1 from '../../../../../3rdParty/jquery.dataTables.min';
import * as dt2 from '../../../../../3rdParty/dataTables.bootstrap.min';
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [this](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started) ?
DataTables adapted for Angular, works with v5.0.0